# Fedora 38 boot ISO sees my computer's (Firebat A16 laptop) 1TB SSD /dev/sda but Ubuntu 22.04 boot ISO does NOT

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd

Ubuntu Mate 22.04 live USB boots/runs fine - everything works except recognizing my SDD, /dev/sda.   It doesn't matter what disk or partition utility I use (all the standard ones on the USB plus I added others) they all get the same result, either they don't see /dev/sda or I get an error reading /dev/sda message and the app ends.   The exception is 'disks' which initially, once per boot, shows me all the SSDs /dev/sda partitions, sizes, type but as soon as I click any partition - it goes to error reading and it's one big blank 0 use 1TB partion (although in reality is partitioned and boots Fedora fine).   Formatting it (in Fedora) and starting with a formatted 1TB drive (no matter what type formatted as), it is still invisible to Ubuntu ISO USB!
ANYONE have ANY idea HOW I can get Ubuntu 22.04 to see this SSD drive so I can load Ubuntu?
Thanks!

Comment: You mention Ubuntu 22.04 LTS but give no ideas as to what product or version of the ISO you're using. Was it the original 22.04? from 2022-April or an updated one? and which product (Server? Desktop?) as they have differences in kerenl stack. Your example of Fedora 39 working implies you need to use an updated Ubuntu ISO but didn't specify anything beyond a release of near two years ago.  Trying Ubuntu 23.10 Server/Desktop maybe easier for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.   It was the latest - ubuntu-mate-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso.  I never did get the Mate boot USB to see the drive, but the plain Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS ISO booted and installed from USB without issue, seeing the drive immediately.

Comment: Your last comment highlights were were using a Ubuntu MATE 22.04.3 that used the HWE kernel stack; but you weren't specific as to what Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS ISO, as there are Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS ISOs using the GA, and also HWE kernel stack options. Some Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS ISOs also have OEM kernel stack options meaning different options (*when certain hardware is detected; flavor media does NOT offer this by default!*).. Please be specific with all details (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS is a release, Server, Desktop etc. matter as well as ISO itself where download options exist)

Comment: Even if its unrelated to kernel stack details; Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS is available on different ISOs that use different installers, the `ubiquity` installer used by Ubuntu-MATE cannot upgrade itself (*if internet is connected at install time*) same as `ubiquity` cannot if on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS ISO that uses `ubiquity`, however if using a Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS ISO using `subiquity` it can upgrade itself.... details matter in comparisons (ie. different Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS ISOs exist and you didn't specify which you used)

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED!  WAS able to install plain ole Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
It's ONLY Mate USB ISOs (including previous versions) that doesn't recognize my SSD.
Even now, with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installed, my MATE boot iso cannot see dev/sda.  This includes when I make the bootable ISO with Mate, with Fedora 38, and with this Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I'll gladly settle for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and give up on Mate!!
Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu-MATE contains the same hardware recognition as Ubuntu Desktop, though of course media differences exist (ie. 22.04, 22.04.1, 22.04.2, 22.04.3, 22.04.4..)  Also initial media where the *flavor* media (such as Ubuntu-MATE) includes the GA kernel stack by default at 22.04 (and 22.04.1) instead of newer HWE kernel stack, but identical stacks at 22.04.2 & later (ie. 22.04.3 & new 22.04.4).   You never said what media you used (only providing 22.04) which was requested.   Your solution was likely only using newer Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 media contrasted with older Ubuntu MATE 22.04 media.